# Cursor in select statement in plain PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

I am currently migrating a Java applicaton from Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL. The Oracle version makes massive use of cursors in select statements like this:

```
SELECT ID, TITLE,
       CURSOR (SELECT RS.COL1, RS.COL2, RS.COL3 FROM RELATED_STUFF RS WHERE RS.ITEMID=ITEM.ID) RELATED_STUFF_ENTRIES,
       CURSOR (SELECT MRS.COL1, MRS.COL2, MRS.COL3 FROM MORE_RELATED_STUFF MRS WHERE MRS.ITEMID=ITEM.ID) MORE_RELATED_STUFF_ENTRIES
FROM ITEM;
```

On Java side, the cursor is simply treated like a sub-ResultSet:

```
var relatedStuffRS = (ResultSet) rs.getObject("RELATED_STUFF_ENTRIES");
```

This solution is quite comfortable, especially when querying many columns in the cursor, or even with a second cursor nested within. Concatenation or joins would be extremely ugly.

I could not find any working syntax for the cursor, and the documentation does not mention anything like that either.
Does Postgres really not offer a construct like this? And if not, what would be the best way to work around it? I assume I have to write a "set returning function" replacing each cursor, but then how do I query it in Java?

Comment: So you get one cursor per row? And then iterate over the rows of each "embedded" cursor for each row in the main query? So if you get 1000 rows you get 2001 result sets?

Comment: You can store an open cursor in a `refcursor` variable and return that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The sub selects usually return up to 10 entries per row. So I might get 7 rows of "RELATED_STUFF_ENTRIES" and 4 rows of "MORE_RELATED_STUFF_ENTRIES" in row 1 of the main query, 10 and 5 rows for row 2 of the main query, and so on. So yes, I iterate over the rows of each embedded cursor.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: As far as I understood, I can use refcursors only in PL/pgSQL, right? So you mean I should write a function for each former cursor, returning a refcursor, and then query the functions in my main query?

Comment: That would be an option. But you could also do the simple thing and run three different queries.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I was hoping to keep the changes in Java code low. So I'll give it a try with refcursors. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to be straightforward or easy (or even 100% equivalent).

One solution would be to create a function that accepts a SQL query, then uses dynamic SQL and returns a refcursor.

Something like:

```sql
create or replace function cursor(p_sql text)
  returns refcursor
as
$$
declare
   l_ref refcursor;
begin
  open l_ref for execute p_sql;
  return l_ref;
end;  
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Passing parameters is going to be tricky, but something like this might be enough:

```
select id, title, 
       cursor(format('select rs.col1, rs.col2, rs.col3 from related_stuff rs where rs.item_id = %s', i.id)) as related_stuff_entries
from item i;
```

---

Another option is to return an array of (anonymous) records. That can be retrieved using `ResultSet.getArray()`, but you lose the meta information about column names in the anonymous records.

Something along the lines:

```sql
SELECT id, title,
       array (SELECT (rs.col1, rs.col2, rs.col3) FROM related_stuff RS WHERE rs.itemid = item.id) related_stuff_entries,
       array (SELECT (mrs.col1, mrs.col2, mrs.col3) FROM more_related_stuff mrs WHERE mrs.itemid = item.id) more_related_stuff_entries
FROM item;
```

Note the parentheses around the column list in the embedded queries. They turn the multiple columns into a single column with an anonymous record type.

But this will also be quite ugly to deal with in JDBC. I don't think the JDBC driver has any support for anonymous records.

---

The easiest solution is probably to return the embedded result as a JSON array. It's quite easy to deal with in Java, but the biggest drawback is that you lose the data type information with that conversion.

```
select id, title, 
       (select jsonb_agg(t) from (select rs.c1, rs.c2 from related_stuff rs where rs.item_id = i.id) t) as related
from item i;
```

Note the nested derived table to preserve the column names during the conversion.

Comment: Thank you, @a_horse_with_no_name! I tried the jsonb_agg solution, and it works pretty nice! Still have to try with the "nested nested" cursor, but I'm optimistic! :)